# Programmatically invoke unlock device (iPhone) in jailbreak tweak?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, theos, cydia-substrate

I am designing an iOS 8.1 jailbreak tweak which gives the user an alternative unlock method when swiping left at the lock screen. Once the user is done with some tasks I would like the device to unlock itself; without requesting a passcode. Obviously if necessary the tweak has access to the users passcode.

Now that you have an idea of what I am trying to achieve, I was wondering if one of you knows which method could help me invoke the unlock.

Comment: Who said we're all men?

Comment: Haha fair enough...
To all the beautiful and sophisticated women whom encountered my original message: I AM SORRY.

Comment: I've removed the references to men and/or women from your question as it doesn't *add* anything. Greetings are usually considered noise and to be deleted.